# Cannot open PDF files in AIR application on Mac OS. But same code worked in windows

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe

This code not open PDF files in AIR app on Mac OS. But same code worked in windows.
I installed adobe acrobat reader. But I still face error in MAC os

protected function button2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void

```
        {





            if (HTMLLoader.pdfCapability == HTMLPDFCapability.STATUS_OK){



            var FileDir:File =new  File();

            var FilePath:String = "";               



            try

            {

                // Open browser for choose pdf file for open

                FileDir.browseForOpen("Open As [Only supports .PDF extension with file name.]");



                FileDir.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, readFromDirectory);

                //htmlLoader.parent.removeChild(htmlLoader);

            }

            catch (error:Error)

            {

                trace("Failed:", error.message);

            }



            //***** Browse event complete *****

            function readFromDirectory(event:Event):void

            {   

                try

                {           

                    var newFile:File = event.target as File;

                    FilePath =  newFile.nativePath;



                    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(FilePath); //URL to the file                      



                    htmlLoader.width = 700; //width of the content area



                    htmlLoader.height = 450; //height of the content area



                    htmlLoader.load(url);



                    //wrapping into UIComponent                   



                    holder = new UIComponent();                       

                    holder.addChild(htmlLoader);

                    addElement(holder);              



                }

                catch(err:Error)

                {

                    trace("file not in correct format");

                }

            }   

            }               

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Acrobat Reader on your Mac.